# Execute two functions in a variable

Tags: php, email

I know this is a very novice questions, but I just can't figure it out.
How can I send two mails on one line?

This is my code to send just one mail, wich works fine.

```
$success = mail($EmailTo,$Subject,$Body,$headers);
```

But I want to send the email to the user, and also a copy to my backup email.
Something like this? :

```
$success = { mail($EmailTo,$Subject,$Body,$headers); mail(info@mywebsite.com,$Subject,$Body,$headers); }
```

Comment: Write `header` with `cc`

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use a library like PHPMailer, it makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

save the emails in an array and loop through it

```
$email = ['info@mywebsite.com','abcd@abce.com'];
foreach ($email as $mail) {
mail($mail,$Subject,$Body,$headers);
}
```

or you add a `cc`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send them separately and not use `cc`, you can use logical `AND` or `OR` operators. You probably want `success` to only be `true` when both mails return `true`, so something like this:

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers) && mail('info@mywebsite.com', $Subject, $Body, $headers);
```

Or use separate variables for the success of each mail. This gives you the advantage of knowing which went wrong.

```
$successClient = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);
$successInfo   = mail('info@mywebsite.com', $Subject, $Body, $headers);

if(!$successClient)
    //Some code to log that the first mail failed

if(!$successInfo)
    //Some code to log that the second mail failed
```

Answer (score 0):

`$Emailto = "me@gmail.com, you@gmail.com"`

`$success = mail($Emailto,$Subject,$Body,$headers);`

mail accepts many recipients as long as you separate them with a comma